# Trigger to insert data row into new table when old table is updated

Tags: sql-server, trigger

I am trying to set up a trigger in SQL server that when the price of an existing item on table `item` is changed, it inserts that entire item (row) into table `item_price_history`, putting the old price as `old_price` and the updated price as `new_price`. I'm pretty stumped as to how to get this to work. I keep getting errors that `item_id` cannot be bound, or is an invalid column, but it is a column in both tables. Here is what I have so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_price_trg
ON item
AFTER UPDATE,INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
  DECLARE @DATE_OF_CHANGE datetime;
  SET @DATE_OF_CHANGE = GETDATE();
  INSERT INTO item_price_history,item_id,old_price,new_price,date_of_change)
  VALUES (item_id,old.price,new.price,@DATE_OF_CHANGE)
END;
```

Comment: Your code has errors where you don't specify a table to insert into, and you're missing an open paren on the column list for the insert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the correct table names in the trigger -- `inserted` and `deleted` are the internal table names used for the new and old data. Also, you need to associate the two tables correctly, and handle multiple rows simultaneously. Your code will need a rewrite to do all this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_price_trg
ON item
AFTER UPDATE,INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO item_price_history(
        item_id,
        old_price,
        new_price,
        date_of_change
        )
    SELECT 
        i.item_id,
        d.price,
        i.price,
        GETDATE()
    FROM inserted i
    LEFT JOIN deleted d
        ON i.item_id = d.item_id
    WHERE i.price != ISNULL(d.price, -1)
END;
```

Comment: That is the part I was struggling with. I tried the "old.price" and got nowhere. Now I know the right way, and thank you very much for the help!